# because ruby is a dynamic lang, is it easy to create a plugin architecture in a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Say in a action, I want to create points in the code where someone can hook into, without having to go into the controller action and edit my code.

Is this possible?  I guess they would have to hook into my code at some point when the application starts?

I know wordpress has a plugin arch with hooks, wondering if the same can be done in RoR and if there is already a design pattern for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using

1. [Plugins](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html)
2. [Callbacks](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.0.0/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb)

Plugins allows you to extend Rails functionality by injecting more features into the main app. Callbacks allow you to define custom hooks other developers can take advantage of.